# Where is the Nurbs Sphere Start and End Sweep in Maya 2014?

Tags: 3d, maya

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm looking in the `Channel Box` and the `Attribute Editor` for the `Start` and `End Sweep` for a `Nurbs Sphere` I created.

I can't seem to find it. 
*Channel Box, I can't scroll down, there are no more options.*
[image: Channel box]

*Attribute Editor: Can't seem to find it here either*
[image: Attribute Editor]

Comment: Any chance this can be in the [Revolve options](http://3d.about.com/od/Creating-3D-The-CG-Pipeline/ss/Revolving-Curves-With-Maya-Modeling-A-Tea-Set_4.htm)? Why can't you scroll?

Comment: @Yisela - I see it in Revolve options, but that doesn't apply to the existing sphere. IIRC, in Maya 7, the Start & End Sweep were in the Channel box when the geometry was selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out what the problem is. Apparently, because I am trying to edit the sweep on a duplicated shape, it doesn't contain the inputs where the sweep is recorded.

So... I created a new `Nurbs Sphere`, and the inputs line was available in the `Channel box`.

[image: Photo of the Channel box after creating the new sphere]